# event.preventDefault vs. event.returnValue

Tags: javascript

On page 118 of SitePoint's "Simply JavaScript", copyright 2007, they talk about how event.returnValue is used for Internet Explorer.

Q: Is that still true?  IE doesn't have event.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 5):

It's still true, even in Internet Explorer 9 (I just checked). But you should never use browser detection to handle these cases anyways, so just check for the presence of `event.preventDefault` and set `event.returnValue` to `false` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think I'll use return false.  Thanks minitech!

Comment: IE 9 does have `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Tim Down: Only if you have a Strict DOCTYPE, I think, which most people don't, so, just to be on the safe side. But yes, it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975967), IE9 supports `event.preventDefault()`. `event.returnValue` can be used in versions 8 and below.

Edit: I should also mention that I don't have IE9 on my bsd box, so I can't test it atm :P