# issue with event.returnValue=false; in js

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Statements with returnValue</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<A HREF="c:" onclick="event.returnValue=false;alert('The Hyperlink has been cancelled.');">Drive C</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Question:

We have this line: `event.returnValue=false;` but why `alert()` still got excuted? then, what is the purpose to use `event.returnValue=false;`?

Comment: `event.returnValue = false;` is to preventDefault (later after this function finishes executing). Therefore, the rest of this function is still executed

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085418/event-preventdefault-vs-event-returnvalue

Comment: Apart from that, why are you using Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to prevent the default behaviour of the click (in this case, navigating to `"c:"`):

1. `return false` from the event handler. This will immediately exit the current event handler, and prevent any further actions.
2. Set `event.returnValue = false`. This does not immediately stop the current event handler (ie. `onclick`), but once it completes, any further actions will be prevented.

Since `event.returnValue` is not supported in all browsers, I'd definitely recommend using `return false` instead - just don't forget that it needs to be at the end of your onclick handler.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `event.returnValue` is here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It does not, however, change the execution order. You would need to have a `return` statement to change the order of execution:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Statements with returnValue</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<A HREF="c:" onclick="event.returnValue=false; return;alert('The Hyperlink has been    cancelled.');">Drive C</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```